# What GPG agent does Elementary Luna use?

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

Whenever I try decrypting or signing files with GPG in Elementary Luna, I see a graphical password prompt come up for my GPG key.

The key is then cached in memory for future requests for some time. My first thought  was to use `gpg-agent` to purge it from memory or to configure the TTL, but to my surprise, it wasn't installed. `seahorse` also isn't installed.

What is being used as a GPG agent on Elementary Linux?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a GNOME based desktop I believe it's built into GNOME, as part of the `gnome-keyring-daemon`. You can find out the duration the keys are cached using this command:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.crypto.cache gpg-cache-method
'session'
```

You can see the other keys under the `org.gnome.crypto.cache` schema with this command:

```
$ gsettings list-keys org.gnome.crypto.cache
gpg-cache-authorize
gpg-cache-method
gpg-cache-ttl
```

The "keyring" process will show like so:

```
$ ps -eaf|grep [k]eyring
saml      2444     1  0 Jun04 ?        00:00:33 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
```

If you want the daemon to flush it's cached contents:

```
$ gnome-keyring-daemon -r -d
```

If you really want a GUI to manage the contents then install `seahorse` to do so. There isn't a default application that I'm aware of which is typically included with GNOME.

```
$ seahorse
```

[image: ss #1]

#### References

- [Customizing the GNOME Shell](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2011/03/customizing-the-gnome-3-shell.html)
- [GNOME Keyring](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Keyring)